# How create name value pairs array from command line arguments?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, command-line-arguments

Consider example:

```
bash myScript.sh --name1 valule1 --name2 value2
```

Inside `myScript.sh`:

```
java -jar someJar. jar --name1=valule1 --name2=value2
```

E.g. array `--name1 valule1 --name2 value2` needs to transform into name/value pairs: `--name1=valule1 --name2=value2`

How to that with bash?

Comment: This is *your* script. Is there any reason not to make it support `--name1=valule1 --name2=value2` syntax?

Comment: because I am not scrit caller so it can be called with space parameters 
only. And I have to create pairs for jar invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Build up an array holding the newly formatted options for your jar:

```
# keep looping while the 2nd parameter is not null
while [[ -n "$2" ]]; do
    jaropts+=( "$1=$2" )
    shift 2
done
echo java -jar someJar.jar "${jaropts[@]}"
```

Comment: Got `line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file` :(

Comment: Also it is just only for 2 parameters not for whole command line array

Comment: That syntax error is not coming from my code. Show your current code.

Comment: "just only for 2 parameters" -- what do you mean? Show how you actually invoke your script.